# Can I use Lucky Cigarette Case on another player

Tags: eldritch-horror

My question is rather simple, but we can't quite put a finger on the correct answer. Items such as the Lucky Cigarette Case ... can we use them on other player rolls or just our own? The text says to add 1 to the result of a single die roll ... but doesn't specify on whom you can use it. Any help would be neato, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, unless an item specifically says it can be used on other investigators (e.g., "Choose an investigator"), it can only be used on/by the person holding the item.

Comment: Thank you! We were just not sure about it. Decided that using it on anyone was just too powerful, seems we made the correct assumption.

Answer (score 0):

The Q & A for the Grotesque Statue artifact in the FAQ strongly implies that items by default can only be used on the investigator that owns the item, as the wording similarly doesn't call out that it can be used on other investigators.

> Q  Can the Grotesque Statue Artifact prevent other investigators from losing Sanity?
>
> A. No. The Grotesque Statue Artifact’s second effect allows the investigator to spend one Clue to prevent himself from losing Sanity from a single e ect. It does not allow him to prevent any other investigator from losing Sanity.